# Scanf skips first input and then accepts two inputs seemingly simultaneously

Tags: c, input, scanf

The main function of my c program contains this code:

```
    printf("Please enter your username: ");
    char user[50];
    scanf(" %s",&user);
    FILE* events;
    events = fopen(user,"a+");
    rewind(events);
    printf("Here are the events this user has saved: \n");
    char c = fgetc(events); 
    while (c != EOF) 
    { 
        printf ("%c", c); 
        c = fgetc(events); 
    }
    rewind(events);
    printf("\nPlease input 1 if you would like to add an event or 0 if not.");
    int addEvents;
    scanf(" %d ",&addEvents);//this line is going off the rails somehow!
    if(addEvents==1){
        addEvent(events);
    }
```

and only a few lines later (skipping over some variable initializations), this:

```
monthInput:
        printf("Please input the month (a number from 1-12), or input 13 to display a yearly calendar: ");
        scanf(" %d", &month);
    if(month<1||month>13){
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
        goto monthInput;
    }
```

The problem I am having is that the line denoted by comment is not properly accepting input. If I input a 1, I have to input another 1 before it is recognized. Then, the addEvent function begins and runs normally, until the program reaches another scanf statement. As soon as any input is had, the program jumps to monthInput and just infinitely loops. If I input a 0, I have to input another 0 before it is recognized, and one of these is given to the monthInput segment, so that it produces this output:

```
Please enter your username: jack
Here are the events this user has saved: 

Please input 1 if you would like to add an event or 0 if not.0
0
CALENDAR
Please input the month (a number from 1-12), or input 13 to display a yearly calendar: Invalid input.
Please input the month (a number from 1-12), or input 13 to display a yearly calendar:
```

I have no clue what could be causing this error, although I don't have much experience using goto's and have heard that they can be dangerous... maybe this is the source of my plight. I don't think that the scanf is reading whitespace as I have included spaces around the formatting codes and the input is formatted as integers rather than characters or strings anyway.

Comment: I would guess the output buffering is interfering. Either always end a printf with a newline or add `fflush(stdout);` after the printf line to force the prompt to show.

Comment: You're not checking any return values from `scanf()`.  You don't really know what it's doing.

Comment: Get rid of the space AFTER `%d` in `scanf()`.

Comment: The leading space in the `" %s"` format skips white space (unnecessarily but harmlessly; the `%s` conversion specification skips white space automatically), but `%s` leaves the newline in the input buffer.  The `"%c"` format does not skip white space (it would be correct to use `" %c"` here) so the first call reads the newline leftover from reading the file name.  Note that the leading white space in `" %d "` is unnecessary (but harmless); the training white space is devastating for the UX unless you're certain that the input will never be from a terminal.